# RGB to HSV is same as BGR to HSV?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, color-space

I am using OpenCV for colour space conversions. I was wondering if RGB to HSV conversion and BGR to HSV conversions will give me the same output?

```
cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img),cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV) # BGR to HSV
```

Because according to my assumption the only difference between RGB and BGR is a shift in channels, then by converting an RGB to HSV isn't it same as converting BGR to HSV?

Comment: By selecting `BGR2HSV` or `RGB2HSV`, you're telling OpenCV what order the channels are in. OpenCV does not independently know which channel is the `B` channel, for instance.

Comment: My requirement is building HSV images from RGB by using this line of code cv2.cvtColor(np.float32(img),cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV). Does it give me right saturation and hue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

they will not be the same. BGR is not RGB. the order of channels is *reversed*.

the wrong conversion type will give nonsensical Hue values. the right conversion type will give identical Hue values.

Saturation and Value will be the same by virtue of the HSV model not respecting the differing brightness of the primary colors.

Comment: thank you, So, BGR and RGB will give me two different HUE values but the other two channels will be the same? Opencv considers BGR order, so does cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_RGB2HSV)  gives me RGB to HSV conversion?

Comment: I placed it in transform.compose. So the Intpu images are PIL images.

Comment: PIL images are commonly RGB order. convert to numpy array, which will have RGB order as well, then use cvtColor with RGB2HSV because that is the channel order you have.